# Change toggle button drawable at activity start in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin, togglebutton

[image]

I made two toggle buttons and i edited the toggle button style to change the toggle image on state change like the above code

this my toggle button

```
<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/speaker"
                android:layout_width="25dip"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/speaker_btn" />
```

and this  **drawable/speeker_btn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- When selected, use grey -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_on"
        android:state_checked="true" />
  <!-- When not selected, use white-->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_off"
      android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

And im using static boolean variable to store the toggle status global to use it again in another activity 
so what i want is to change the button drawable on activity created without clicking the toggle 
i tried this code

```
speakerToggle = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.speaker);
if(speaker_btn_checked == true ){
       speakerToggle.checked  = true; 
}
```

But its look like recheck the toggle button again i just need to change the drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by replacing ToggleButton by Button, and change the button image programmatically from the activity class, and created static variable for the button status so my code became like this

```
 Button speakerToggle = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.speaker);

    speakerToggle.Click += delegate{         
        if (am.SpeakerphoneOn == false)
        {
        speakerToggle.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.speaker_on);
        }else{
        speakerToggle.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.speaker_off);
        }
    };
```

And inside the **onCreate** method i created this

```
if (am.SpeakerphoneOn == true){
    speakerToggle.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.speaker_on);
}else{
    speakerToggle.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.speaker_off);
}
```

And it works very well !!